# Can we display custom lightning component in highlights panel of record page?

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I am trying to display a lightning component as a button on the lightning record page in the highlights panel beside standard salesforce buttons. Is there any way to add custom component within highlights panel?

Note: Cant use quickaction feature due to modal dialog box popup.[image: something like this]

Comment: So you want to click on a button to display your component, but directly in the page, not in a modal ?

Comment: Yes that button when clicked  would update a field and display success toast message .

Comment: the place where you indicate in the image is where all the SF1 and lightning actions go, are you open to putting the button right under that highlights panel? if you are open then it is possible to create a custom component and just throw it on the pagelayout.

Comment: @Rao Ya I was looking to see if we can put right beside the Sf actions/buttons. If there is no workaround then having the component right below highlights panel will be the only option I guess.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a perfect solution for now but you have several options:

- You can make use of the [Lightning Component Quick Action](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/lightning_component_actions.htm) anyway and do something like this:

  - Your markup would just display a waiting message, like "Updating", why not with a spinning wheel. The idea is that with this solution you have to display a modal, so just display a waiting message for the user instead of a white modal
  - Do your update using your component, using JS Controller / Apex
  - Fire both `force:closeQuickAction` and `force:showToast` events once your work is done. This will display your message in the Toast, and close the modal without any manual interaction from the user
- Use a Visualforce page in a Detail Page Button, this will redirect you for maybe 1 second to a white page, Apex Controller will do the work and redirect back to your record with a PageReference. You won't be able to show the toast though.
- Use a custom button that you'll put on your page through AppBuilder. You'll be able to do what you want but the button will be somewhere else on the page, so it might be confusing for users.

Comment: Appreciate your inputs. Could you please elaborate on the first point you mentioned please.

Comment: I've added a few details, tell me if it's enough.

Comment: Yes that's makes more clear. Is there a way we could have the standard button displayed on highlights panel can be morphed in to custom lightning component? If yes then that would be great help and resolve my problem.

Comment: You can't replace a standard button with a Lightning Component for now. The only way to use a Lightning Component in the standard list of button is to display it through the modal.